# Slowest websites statistics from squid logs

Tags: squid

I am sysadmin and would like to deny ad websites on squid level.. but not all, just slowest ones...

Is it possible to get a statistics of most slowest websites squid accessing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use the [default squid logfile format](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LogFormat) for your [access.log](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidLogs#access.log), to see the slowest requests, try something like:

```
grep -w MISS /path/to/squid/access.log | cut -f 2,7 -d ' ' | sort -nr
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked in my case: cat access.log | gawk '{print $2,$7}' | sort -nr

Comment: @DennisYurichev Please note that gawk can open files directly, no need for cat. :)